# Mapping DataFrame data on to USA and Canada Map in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a Dataframe of the format

```
CA  |   120030
FL  |   980101
MA  |   898111
```

Where the first column represents a state in USA or Canada. Is there a way to map the values to a map for visualization.

Comment: do you have the geometries for the states?

Comment: If this is a python question, why is there a `ggplot2` tag?  Are you trying to emulate something which is done in the `ggplot2` package?

Comment: Use basemap, Cartopy, or geopandas. If you have trouble using any of them, come back and ask a specific question about your problem.

Answer (score -1):

See `basemap` from matplotlib.

Here is a link to its documentation: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/